# What are the optimal strategies for the "prime-game"?

Tags: game-theory, nash-equilibrium, simplex

A and B are playing the following game :

A and B choose a number from 1 to 100, not knowing the number chosen by the
opponent.

A wins if the sum of the chosen numbers is prime, otherwise B wins.

Which mixed strategies are optimal for A and B ? Which player wins
with which probability, if both play optimal ?

This optimal strategy can be calculated with the simplex algorithm, but I
did not have access to a program calculating large simplex tableaus.

Is there an easier method to solve such games ?

If I remember right, I found out that player B wins between $\frac{6}{11}$ and $\frac{3}{5}$ units per game , but I do not remember the strategies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sum is $\le 200$ hence any composite number has one of the primes $2,3,5,7,11,13$ as a factor.
If for some $0\le n\le 70$, $B$ picks one of the numbers $n+1, n+2, \ldots, n+30$ at random (each with same probability) then the distribution $A+B\bmod 30$ will be uniformly random, hence $A+B$ will have a divisor $\in\{2,3,5\}$ with probability $\frac{22}{30}=\frac{11}{15}$ (i.e. this divisibility fails only if the remainder $\mod 30$ is one of $1,7, 11, 13, 17,19,23,29$). Also, $A+B\ge n+2$ so that a choice of $n\ge 4$ guarantees that $A+B$ is composite with probability at least $\frac{11}{15}$.
Since already this simple strategy gives $B$ an expected winning probability greater than $\frac35$, you seem to remember wrong.

By the same argument, $A$ can enforce that the smallest divisor of $A+B$ is $>5$ with probability at least $\frac 4{15}$. The only composite numbers with this property up to $200$ are $7^2, 7\cdot 11, 7\cdot 13, 7\cdot 17, 7\cdot19, 7\cdot 23, 11^2,11\cdot 13, 11\cdot 17, 13^2$. It is feasible that a suitable choice of $n$ is able to modtly avoid theseten numbers, thus allowing $A$ to *almost* reach this upper limit of $\frac4{15}$.

For a precise result, it seems one really has to try something like the simplex approach you suggested.

Comment: It was the expected win : If the probability is 0.8 to win the game, the expected win is 0.6 per game. This was what I calculated.

Comment: it would be sufficient to find a nash equilibrium, but this seems to be very difficult.

Comment: I wonder why I cannot start my comments with @hagen here ...

Comment: Nice approach @hagen